# How to spawn a single worker instance from parent thant is being spawned multiple times?

Tags: node.js

I have a server and a scraper. The server spawns the scraper, but the server is being spawned multiple times by pm2 depending on the machine core count. I want the server to be spawned multiple times but only execute one instance of scraper. Is this possible?

```js
// index.js (this should be forked multiple times)
const server = http.createServer(handler);
require('./scraper'); // this shoud only be forked once
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need some kind of common place to store startup information. file system, socket, memory etc

```
function runOnce(fn) {
  const http = require('http');
  http.createServer()
    .on('error', _=> console.log('skip'))
    .listen(9999, _=> fn() && console.log('run'));
}

runOnce(_ => require('./scraper'));
```